# How to characterize Cohen-Macaulay curves that are Gorenstein in codimension 0?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme which is Cohen-Macaulay (preferentially of dimension 1). Then we say that $X$ is *Gorenstein in codimension $\leq r$* (which we denote as '$X$ is $G_r$') if all local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ of dimension $\leq r$ are Gorenstein rings.

> I am interested in the one dimensional case and want to grasp what it really means to be $G_0$ in that case.

Since the local rings in question have dimension zero, we are only talking about the local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ where $P$ is a generic point of $X$.

By definition, a zero-dimensional local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m}, k)$ is Gorenstein iff
$$\dim_k \operatorname{Hom}_R(k,R) = 1.$$

I figured out two other characterizations:

1. Given by Dieudonne: A zero-dimensional local ring $R$ is Gorenstein iff $R$ is injective.
2. Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be an artinian lcoal ring (e.g. noetherian and zero-dimensional), then the following are equivalent:

   - $R$ is Gorenstein,
   - all finite $R$-modules are reflexive,
   - $I = \operatorname{Ann} \operatorname{Ann} I$ for all ideals $I \subset R$, and
   - for all non-zero ideals $I,J \subset R$: $I \cap J \neq 0$.

These are indeed a lot of formulations for being $G_0$, but still I dont't see what kind of phenomena will occur if $X$ is $G_0$ or when it isn't.

For instance I would like to see a Cohen-Macaulay scheme with a generic point $P$ (with $R := \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$) for which there is no $R$-linear homomorphism from $R/\mathfrak{m}$ to $R$. And to see why this is the case.

Thus some illuminating words and/or examples of both kinds could help me better grasping $G_0$-schemes.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: One nice way to observe the difference between CM and Gorenstein rings/schemes is to look at the dualizing complex - CM means that the complex is isomorphic to an honest sheaf placed in the appropriate degree, and Gorenstein says that this sheaf is in fact a line bundle.

Comment: @KReiser I am aware of that and indeed, I want to find that the dualizing sheaf can be regarded as a $\mathcal{O}_X$-submodule of $\mathcal{K}_X$ (sheaf of meromorphic functions on $X$). This is the case if $X$ is $S_2$ and $G_0$. Also, if $X$ is $G_1$, then this is obviously the case as the dualizing sheaf then is a line bundle.

Comment: In addition to Item 1, for an Artinian local ring (which is always Cohen-Macaulay) $(R,m)$, the canonical module of $R$ is the injective envelope of the residue field, usually, denoted by $E_R(R/m)$. In other words, $R$ is Gorenstein iff $R = E_R(R/m)$.